# for loop - bash script syntax errror

Tags: bash, shell, unix, command

I am a beginner at unix and this is my first for loop with if statement. I am getting an error which says **syntax error near unexpected token 'then'**. Please can you help me fix this. What have i done wrong.

```
for file in $@
do
    if [[ ! -f $@ ]]
    then
           echo "Error. File does not exist."
           exit $ERROR_NO_FILE

    elif
    then
           chmod 755 $file
           echo "File permissions have been changed."
           exit $SUCCESS
    fi
done
```

Comment: `[[ ! -f $@ ]]`? Eh? `-f` can't take an arbitrary number of arguments, and you don't know how many things `$@` will expand to. You want `[[ ! -f "$file" ]]` (lack of quoting acceptable there because of side effects of `[[ ]]`, though it still doesn't hurt).

Comment: Also, you want `for file in "$@"`, `chmod 755 "$file"`, etc; -- as it is, this will break badly with filenames with spaces. Run your code through http://shellcheck.net/ and fix what it finds.

Comment: **DO NOT CHANGE YOUR QUESTION IN A WAY THAT INVALIDATES PREEXISTING ANSWERS**.

Comment: I was wondering why I had to edit the answer for correctness. Now I know, and reverting to the old version. Sorry!

Comment: Do not write `for f in $@`.  Quotes are important.  It should be either `for f in "$@"; do...` or `for f; do ...` unless you have a very special use case and know the difference and you actually want an unquoted $@. In that case you will want to add a comment explaining exactly what motivates the unusual usage.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I have changed the code. Ok i no longer get the error. Thanks for that but now the for loop only changes the file permissions for the first argument and not for the other arguments. Why would this be.

Comment: @pogba123, would need to see a full reproducer with your code and info on how you're invoking it. File a separate question?

Comment: @pogba123, ...actually, the `exit` is the obvious answer -- you're exiting *inside* your loop, not *after* your loop.

Answer (score 1):

there is an extra `elif/then` in the middle. Try replacing it with an `else`

```
       exit $ERROR_NO_FILE

else
       chmod 755 $file
```

Comment: @pogba123, because you still have the extra `then`; you aren't doing exactly what this answer tells you to do.